# Having trouble setting an object to nil in ruby binary search tree

Tags: ruby, pointers, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing a binary search tree in ruby, and I'm attempting to define a function to remove an value from the tree.  The Tree has a @root value that points to a Node object.  which is defined as such:

```
  class Node
    attr_reader :value
    attr_accessor :left, :right

    def initialize value=nil
      @value = value
      @left = nil
      @right = nil
    end

    # Add new value as child node to self, left or ride
    # allows for duplicates, to L side of tree
    def insert new_value
      if new_value <= @value
        @left.nil? ? @left = Node.new(new_value) : @left.insert(new_value)
      elsif new_value > @value
        @right.nil? ? @right = Node.new(new_value) : @right.insert(new_value)
      end
    end
  end
```

Thus, the nodes all hold references to their L & R children.  Everything works on the tree, inserting, traversing, performing a breadth-first-search (level-order-traverse) to return a Node value, if found.

The problem I'm having is when trying to remove a Node object.  I can't figure out how to set the actual OBJECT to nil, or to its child, for example, rather than reassigning a POINTER/variable to nil and the object still existing.

Tree has two functions that are supposed to do this (you can assume that breadth_first_search correctly returns the appropriate found node, as does smallest_r_child_of)

```rb
  def remove value
    node = breadth_first_search(value)
    return false if node.nil?

    remove_node(node)
  end

  def remove_node node
    if node.left.nil? && node.right.nil?
      node = nil
    elsif !node.left.nil? && node.right.nil?
      node = node.left
    elsif node.left.nil? && !node.right.nil?
      node = node.right
    else
      node = smallest_r_child_of(node)
    end

    return true
  end
```

I thought that by passing in the actual node object to `remove_node`, that I could call `node = ____` and the like to reassign the actual object to something else, but all it does, as far as I can tell, is reset the `node` argument variable/pointer, while not actually reassigning my data at all.

Does anyone have any tips/suggestions on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Changing `node` has zero impact on the caller. Everything you do in `remove_mode` manipulates a *local variable* and does nothing to the `node` inside of `remove(value)`.

Comment: @Jörg has given a good answer, which I do not think is likely to be improved upon, but you do yourself a disservice by selecting an answer so quickly, as it may well discourage other answers. Moreover, it may be considered a bit rude by those still working on their answers. Many askers wait a minimum of a couple of hours before making a selection; some wait considerably longer to allow readers around the world who are then fast asleep a chance to offer answers. There is no rush to make a selection. Please bear that in mind in future.

Comment: Fair enough, Cary.  I'll keep that in mind for the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "set an object to `nil`". An object can never change its class, it either is an instance of `Node` or it is an instance of `NilClass`, it cannot at one point in time be an instance of `Node` and at another point in time be an instance of `NilClass`.

Likewise, an object cannot change its identity, object #4711 will always be object #4711, however, `nil` is a singleton, so there is only one `nil` and it has the same identity during the entire lifetime of the system.

What you *can* do is to bind the *variable* which references the object to `nil`. You are doing the opposite operation inside your `insert` method.

Comment: Thanks Jörg.  That makes sense.  I guess I will need add a little extra logic to keep track of/identify parent Nodes efficiently, so I can set the references to the Nodes-to-be-removed to nil, thus sending them to the garbage collector.